# Usage of quotes in PHP shell_exec() command

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have come across an interesting situation with the shell_exec() function in PHP. This command works:

```
$res = shell_exec("mdb-export -D \"%d/%m/%y\" ".$this->mdbFileName." ".$tableName." &> " . $outputFile);
```

However, this command does not work:

```
$res = shell_exec("mdb-export -D \"%d/%m/%y\" ".$this->mdbFileName." \"".$tableName."\" &> " . $outputFile);
```

When entering the command in a shell (either way - with or without quotes around the table name) it works fine. I would really like to know why the first set of escaped quotes does not affect shell_exec():

```
\"%d/%m/%y\"
```

But the second set:

```
\"".$tableName."\"
```

Does not allow shell_exec to execute. FYI: all file name variables in the script are full file paths. They were entered in the exact same way when testing in the shell. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Upon failure, shell_exec returns NULL and the command is not executed.

Comment: Instead of just saying it doesn't work, provide an error message or further insight into the actual problem.

Comment: Hi Devon, no error message. shell_exec() returns NULL and the command is not executed. I will edit my post to reflect that.

Comment: Try echoing it without the redirect.  shell_exec("echo mdb-export...");  See what is actually being executed.

Comment: Just tried it from the actual script and got an empty echo. However, you got me thinking about the return var and I tried putting it into another file containing only the shell_exec and shell_exec executed the command. I am now thinking something must be wrong with my script other than shell_exec().... Once I figure out what is going on, I will post my findings if they are relevant to the usage of quotes passed into shell_exec().

Answer (score 0):

After some more testing, it appears that the $tableName variable contained an extra space. Another part of the program was pulling the table name from the MDB file and left a trailing space.

When echoing out the $tableName variable everything appeared fine because the space was invisible. When running shell_exec without quotes surrounding the table name, the command executed because no errors occur if there are extra spaces between parameters. However, when surrounding the variable with quotes, the mdb-export program started looking for:

```
"tableName "
```

instead of

```
"tableName"
```

causing a silent, yet complete failure.